# Velocity of an object

Tags: calculus

Let $V (t) = t^2−4t+4$ represent the velocity of an object
in meters per second.
(a) What is the object’s initial velocity?
(b) When is the object not moving?
(c) Identify the concavity of the velocity graph.

Can any one explain how to do b and c

Comment: If the object is not moving then $V(t) = 0$. So you have to find the roots of $V(t)$. For the last, you can plot $V(t)$.

Comment: Hint for (a): The object's initial velocity is when $t=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
b) Find $t$ such that $V(t)=t^2−4t+4=0$.
c) Show that $V''(t)>0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.